# python error: an integer is required

Tags: python

I'm working on my python script 
I have got a very weird error  when I'm trying to use the method `cv2.getGaussianKernel()`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
g_kernel =cv2.getGaussianKernel((300, 300), 8.0, ktype= cv2.CV_32F)
img = cv2.imread('LR_intermediate_.jpg')
filtered_img = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)
h, w = g_kernel.shape[:2]
g_kernel = cv2.resize(g_kernel, (3*w, 3*h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow('gabor kernel (resized)', g_kernel)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Mohammed/PycharmProjects/GaborFilter/Gaborscript.py", line
>   3, in 
>   g_kernel =cv2.getGaussianKernel((300, 300), 8.0, ktype= cv2.CV_32F)
>   TypeError: an integer is required

May anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try 8 instead of 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

In your line:

```
g_kernel =cv2.getGaussianKernel((300, 300), 8.0, ktype= cv2.CV_32F)
```

(300,300) is not an int.

Could you try with

```
g_kernel =cv2.getGaussianKernel(300, 8.0, ktype= cv2.CV_32F)
```

You have the doc for the function there:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html

> Python: cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize, sigma[, ktype]) → retval
>
> ksize – Aperture size. It should be odd ( \texttt{ksize} \mod 2 = 1 ) and positive.